# What is the algorithm behind Random.next()?

Tags: c#, .net

Every built-in method will have its algorithm to perform the function. I'm wondering how exactly Random.Next() can achieve in generating random numbers? What is the algorithm behind it?

To ask this question in another way: If there is no Random class, how would you write a method to generate random numbers?

Comment: All of the source code is [available](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs)

Comment: Here is the source - [Random.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The current implementation of the Random class is based on Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm.